# Overloading input/output operators, why does it work this one way vs this other?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

THE PROBLEM: I'm getting a linker error regarding these two operators. More specifically here are the exact error messages:

NOTE: I have a 'working solution' if you read to the bottom I mention it. I don't know why it works that way and not this way though. I would prefer this method to work because it looks cleaner not having the input/output operator hanging out above my declarations. Sorry for length. I trimmed out unnecessary things like other overloaded operators I had in place since they aren't relevant.

```
poly.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Poly &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVPoly@@@Z) already defined in lab1.obj
1>poly.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Poly const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVPoly@@@Z) already defined in lab1.obj
1>d:\... fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

In my .h file (as you'll see below) I have both desired operators declared as friends so that they can access private members. I also have them as non-member functions, which is what the operator overloading 'guide' on this website says is proper. The operator>> is incomplete but that shouldn't have anything to do with this. I have an idea that it might have to do with the fact that in two places I have "#include iostream" and since the .cpp includes the .h then it's pissing out because of that? Not sure if that's a proper hunch or not. Here is the full .h file:

```
//file poly.h

#ifndef POLY_H
#define POLY_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Poly {

public:
    Poly(int = 0, int = 0);                     //default constructor
    Poly(const Poly &);                         //copy constructor
    ~Poly();                                    //destructor

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Poly& thePoly);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Poly& thePoly);

private:
    int* polynomial;
    int maxExponent;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Poly& thePoly) {

    return input;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Poly& thePoly) {
    bool isZero = true;

    for (int i = thePoly.maxExponent; i > 0; i--) {
        if (thePoly.polynomial[i] != 0) {
            if (thePoly.polynomial[i] < 0) {
                output << " -";
            }
            else {
                output << " +";
            }

            output << thePoly.polynomial[i];

            if (i != 0) {
                output << "x";
            }
            if (i != 1) {
                output << "^";
            }

            output << i;
            isZero = false;
        }
    }

    if (isZero) {
        output << " 0";
    }

    return output;
}

#endif
```

Here is the secondary file that is referenced in the linking errors:

```
// DO NOT change anything in this file. Your code must compile and give the
// correct output with this main on the linux machines.

// Make sure the file containing the member function source is: poly.cpp
// Use all lowercase in the file names.

// This main does not do a thorough job of testing.  When testing arrays,
// be sure to test the middle and also all the boundary conditions.  Test
// values on the boundary and outside the boundaries, i.e., too big/small.

#include "poly.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Poly A(5, 7), B(3, 4), C(2), D(A), X, Y;
    Poly A2, B2, Z1, Z2;

    // set polynomials A and B to desired values
    // A = +5x^7 -4x^3 +10x -2
    // B = +3x^4 +1x^3 
    cout << "Enter terms for polynomial A.  Enter a coefficient " << endl
        << "then exponent for each term. Enter -1 -1 to terminate." << endl;
    cin >> A;                                     // or use a bunch of setCoeff
    cout << "Enter terms for polynomial B.  Enter a coefficient " << endl
        << "then exponent for each term. Enter -1 -1 to terminate." << endl;
    cin >> B;                                     // or use a bunch of setCoeff

    // outputs exactly what is in quotes: "A = +5x^7 -4x^3 +10x -2"
    cout << "A =" << A << endl;
    // outputs exactly what is in quotes: "B = +3x^4 +1x^3"
    cout << "B =" << B << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Strangely (well to me at least) is that if I forgo the declarations and move the entire functions above the public declarations but still within the class then the program compiles properly WHY IS THIS???... of course I haven't been able to test whether this compiling properly means its working properly because I need to finish the operator>> so that I can input data and then output it.

This is what I mean by the above change:

```
#ifndef POLY_H
#define POLY_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Poly {

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Poly& thePoly) {

        return input;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Poly& thePoly) {
        bool isZero = true;

        for (int i = thePoly.maxExponent; i > 0; i--) {
            if (thePoly.polynomial[i] != 0) {
                if (thePoly.polynomial[i] < 0) {
                    output << " -";
                }
                else {
                    output << " +";
                }

                output << thePoly.polynomial[i];

                if (i != 0) {
                    output << "x";
                }
                if (i != 1) {
                    output << "^";
                }

                output << i;
                isZero = false;
            }
        }

        if (isZero) {
            output << " 0";
        }

        return output;
    }

public:
    Poly(int = 0, int = 0);                     //default constructor
    Poly(const Poly &);                         //copy constructor
    ~Poly();                                    //destructor

private:
    int* polynomial;
    int maxExponent;
};



#endif
```

Comment: If you write the body of a free function (like your `operator<<`) in a header you must mark it as `inline`, otherwise you violate the ODR, with the results you see (typically linker errors).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Well that definitely resolved that problem. Mind explaining what ODR stands for?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(moving from the comments)*

If you write the body of a free function (like your operator<<) in a header you must mark it as inline, otherwise you violate the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), with the results you see (typically linker errors).